# W.write, quote issues in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I need to write into a file using w.write python

```
list=['sp1','sp2']

for names list:
 w =open("file_"+str(names)+".txt","w")
 w.write("tab= pd.read_csv('/path1/path2/"+str(names)+"/path/file.txt',sep='\\t')\n\n")
```

so here I should create 2 files :

```
file_sp1.txt
  content -> tab= pd.read_csv("/path1/path2/sp1/path/file.txt",sep='\t')
file_sp2.txt
  content -> tab= pd.read_csv("/path1/path2/sp2/path/file.txt",sep='\t')
```

But it seems that the `"+str(names)+"` is not recognised as a variable, I guess it is a quote issue?

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. First, you need to use `in`, just like @Daí said. Also, you need to close your file (otherwise you may face unexpected complications, like getting and empty second file). You can avoid that by using `with`.

If you're using Python >= 3.6:

```py
names = ['sp1','sp2']

for name in names:
    with open(f"file_{name}.txt","w") as file:
        file.write(f"tab= pd.read_csv('/path1/path2/{name}/path/file.txt',sep='\\t')\n\n")
```

Note that I replaced `list` by `names` since `list` is built-in function (it would not raise an error, but it's a good practice to avoid using them as variable names).

---

For instance, all the lines in the code below format the strings equally (same output):

```py
f"file_{name}.txt"
"file_{}.txt".format(name)
"file_%s.txt" % name
"file_" + name + ".txt"
```

Comment: You should use ``os.path.join`` for crafting the directory name instead of fancy f-string tricks.

Comment: @EkremDinçel, this out of the question escope. The OP already has a defined value for writing, changing just a value in the string. The path should work for him, as he wrote it.

Comment: why is there a `f` before each  path ?

Comment: It's a modern string format (f-string) in Python. See [this blog post](https://www.google.com/search?q=f-strings+python&oq=f-strings+python&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j0i22i30l5j69i60.2312j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to understand it better. You can use the same syntax of your question (don't need to call `str()`, though). See updated note in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should write

```
for names in list:
```